# Vector Network Analyzer - The effect of increasing the number of measurement points

Tags: measurement, spectrum-analyzer

Does increasing the number of measurment points make the measurement time longer?

RBW value does change the time, but does sweep bother the time of taking a single sample?

I'm looking for disadvantages of increasing the number of points from e.g. 201 to 401 while measuring frequency response of a low pass filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Sweep time is proportional to number of points.

The VNA stops at each frequency, measures and moves on.

The amount of time spent at each frequency is also related to the RBW (really just IF Bandwidth), plus some settling time, but the number of points is a simple multiplier.

There is a lot of good information in the Agilent and R&S documents - just google *Agilent VNA sweep time number of points* and you'll find some white papers that will explain things better than I can.  For example, [this one](http://cp.literature.agilent.com/litweb/pdf/5965-8166E.pdf) describes the number of points required to measure a filter.